# Плавное перекрашивание(заливка) заднего фона экрана(элемента)

Tags: java, android

Ребят, недавно делал кастомный динамический progressBar, который менял цвет в зависимости от значения переменной. Пришлось вручную создать несколько xml файлов, в каждом задал свой цвет. Если переменная равна от 0 до 10, то цвет зеленый, от 10-20 - оранжевый и т.д. Но скачки резкие. Вот подумал, а как можно реализовать плавные переходы по цвету без создания миллиарда xml?

Один пример Drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip
        android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom" >
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />

            <solid android:color="#6affbe" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Пример аниматор xml:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="fillColor"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="1200"
    android:valueTo="#71ffb0"
    android:valueFrom="#00ff3c"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:valueType="colorType" />
```

Фрагмент кода из MainActivity:

```
if(mprogressbaru.getProgress() >= 0 && mprogressbaru.getProgress() < 45 ) mprogressbaru.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.verticalprogressbar));
        if(mprogressbaru.getProgress() >= 45 && mprogressbaru.getProgress() < 90) mprogressbaru.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barstep2));
        if(mprogressbaru.getProgress() >= 90 && mprogressbaru.getProgress() < 150) mprogressbaru.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barstep3));
        if(mprogressbaru.getProgress() >= 150 && mprogressbaru.getProgress() < 240) mprogressbaru.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barstep4));
        if(mprogressbaru.getProgress() >= 240 && mprogressbaru.getProgress() < 300) mprogressbaru.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barstep5));
```

Comment: Добавьте код, связанный с проблемой. Никто не в курсе, что именно вы там делали недавно со своим прогрессбаром, чтобы он менял цвет в зависимости от переменной

Answer (score 5, accepted):

я бы предложил вам такой вариант

```
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        view.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

тут ключевой момент в том, что нужно правильные evaluator использовать, для цветов нужен `ArgbEvaluator`, чтобы переход был корректный.

Comment: Этот способ точно в разы элегантнее моего, все работает, спасибо